# SQL Server / .Net bug?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STOCK_WEB](
    [STOCKCODE] [char](23) NOT NULL,
    [SALES_HTML] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [PICTURE_URL] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DateUpdatedLast] [smalldatetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_STOCK_WEB_DateUpdated]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK__STOCK_WEB__094028A5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STOCKCODE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

After inserting some data, update all rows to one date value for snapshot purpose

```
UPDATE STOCK_WEB 
SET DateUpdatedLast = getdate()
WHERE DateUpdatedLast is NULL
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure insertwebshow, Line 6
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

There is a trigger on the table...

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.insertwebshow
ON [ADX].[dbo].[STOCK_WEB]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
    UPDATE [dbo].[STOCK_ITEMS] 
    SET [WEB_SHOW] = 'Y' 
    WHERE [STOCKCODE] = (Select [STOCKCODE] FROM inserted)
GO
```

Could the trigger be returning more than one row for the whole update statement?

This makes no sense whatsoever!

EDIT:
Decided to change trigger before I got the better accepted answer below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.insertwebshow
    ON [ADX].[dbo].[STOCK_WEB]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS 
        UPDATE [dbo].[STOCK_ITEMS] 
        SET [WEB_SHOW] = 'Y' 
        WHERE [STOCKCODE] IN (SELECT [STOCKCODE] FROM inserted)
    GO
```

Comment: My psychic senses tell me the table has a trigger which assumes that the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables will only have one row per trigger execution.

Comment: It's almost _never_ a bug in {SQL Server, .NET, Windows}.

Comment: It's exactly as @Blorgbeard said. In fact, he should answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Could the trigger be returning more than one row for the whole update statement?"

Yes - you are updating every row with a null `DateUpdatedLast`, in one statement. This causes **one** trigger execution, so your trigger must handle multiple rows in the `inserted` table.

This is a common error with triggers, it's easy to miss it if you only do simple one-row tests.

In your case, instead of a subquery, you could use a join:

```
UPDATE si SET [WEB_SHOW] = 'Y' 
FROM [dbo].[STOCK_ITEMS] si 
JOIN inserted i on i.[STOCKCODE] = si.[STOCKCODE]
```